# A basic property of Lebesgue integrability

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Problem: $f$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R}$, prove there exists $h_n\to0$ where $h_n\in(0,1)$ such that $f(x+h_n)\to f(x)\ a.e\ x\in\mathbb{R}$

I tried to prove $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mid f(x+h_n)-f(x)\mid<\infty\ a.e\ x\in\mathbb{R}$, but I got stuck. I'm not sure if it's a promising way.

Comment: Hint: it is enough to show that for example $f_n(x):=f(x+\frac{1}{n})\to f(x)$ in $L^1$. Then there will be a subsequence which converges to $f$ almost everywhere.

Comment: @ Oliver Thank you! In fact, the question in the link you attached is one of the questions I asked a few days ago. I noticed that you gave an answer to that question as well. Unfortunately, I haven't learned topology yet, so it's difficult for me to understand your answer. Anyway, thank you for helping me twice :)

Comment: @Guanfei: You don't need to be an exert in topology, it is enough to know about closed bounded sets in the real line. The proof (as indicated by Mark) and proved in many places is based on the fact that functions of compact support are dense in $L_1$. You can do without that and used step functions, but that would make estimates a little more tedious. In any case, use the result from your previous question and applying to simple functions. Then use the fact that you can approximate any integrable function  by simple functions in $L_1$, that is simple functions a are dense in $L_1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion:

1. In a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3733946/prove-lim-h-rightarrow0me-deltaeh-0-for-measurable-set-e-with-fini/3734833#3734833), it was establesihed that for for any set of finite measure $E$, $\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\mu((E+h)\Delta E)=\|\mathbb{1}_{E+h}-\mathbb{1}_E\|_1\rightarrow0$ as $h\rightarrow0$.
2. Using (1), one can show that for any integrable simple function $s$, $\|s(\cdot -h)-s\|_1=\int|s(x-h)-s(x)|\,dx\xrightarrow{h\rightarrow0}0$
3. Any function $f\in L_1$ can be approximate by integrable simple function. That is, for any $\varepsilon>0$, there is an integrable  simple function $s$ such that $\|f-s\|_1<\varepsilon$
4. Using (2) and (3) along with
   \begin{aligned}
   \|f(\cdot-h)-f\|_1&\leq\|f(\cdot-h)-s(\cdot+h)\|_1+\|s(\cdot-h)-s\|_1\\
   &=\|f-s\|_1+\|s(\cdot-h)-s\|_1
   \end{aligned}
   one can show that $\lim_{h\rightarrow}\|f(\cdot-h)-f\|_1=0$. (Here the translation invariance property of Lebesgue;s measure plays a role)

---

Back to the original problem. suppose $h_n\rightarrow0$ in $\mathbb{R}$. By (4) $\lim_n\|f(\cdot-h_n)-f\|_1=0$. By a well known result, one can extract a subsequence $h_{n_k}$ along which $f(\cdot+h_{n_k})-f(\cdot)$ converges almost surely.